# Get property of generic object using keyof

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic TypeScript function that recursively looks through a tree structure to find an item with a specific id value.  In order to make it reusable I'm trying to use generics and you just give the function the top level, the id value, and the names of the properties to use for id and children.  Here is my example class:

```
export class Thing{
  name: string;
  id: string;
  children: Thing[];

  constructor(){
    this.name='';
    this.id='';
    this.children=[];
  }
}
```

And the method to find the item by id:

```
export function GetGenericItemById<T>(
  allItems: T[],
  idField: keyof T,
  childrenField: keyof T,
  id: string
): any {
  const item = allItems.find((x) => x[idField] === id);
  if (item != null) {
    return item;
  }

  const subItems = allItems.flatMap((i) => i[childrenField]);

  if (subItems.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return GetGenericItemById(subItems, idField, childrenField, id);
}
```

However, on the find function where it makes the comparison `x[idField] === id` it tells me `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T]' and 'string' have no overlap.`.  The intent here is to get that property from the object and get it's value.  What am I doing wrong here?

I did do this without generics like this:

```
export function GetGenericItemById(
  allItems: any[],
  idField: string,
  childrenField: string,
  id: string
): any {
  const item = allItems.find((x) => x[idField] === id);
  if (item != null) {
    return item;
  }

  const subItems = allItems.flatMap((i) => i[childrenField]);

  if (subItems.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return GetGenericItemById(subItems, idField, childrenField, id);
}
```

This works, however you can also put whatever you want into the `idField` and `childrenField` property so you could mess it up pretty easily.  It would be nice to restrict those to only be valid keys of the type you are using.  I thought my attempt above was doing that but it doesn't seem to be the same since it's giving that error.

**EDIT**

Per request here is a simple example of how I intent to use it.  Say I have a simple data structure that has 'things'.  Each `Thing` has an id and a name as well as potential children that are other `Thing`s.  Like this:

```
const data=[
  {
    name: "thing 1",
    id: "1",
    children: [
      {
        name: "thing 1a",
        id: "1a",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "thing 2",
    id: "2",
    children: [
      {
        name: "thing 2a",
        id: "2a",
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

My intent would be to call the function something like this:

```
const foundThing = GetGenericItemById<Thing>(topThings, 'id', 'children', '1a');
```

In this example `topThings` would be a collection that just contained the top level items (ids 1 and 2 in the sample data).  Basically it just searches down the tree to find that item.  I would expect `foundThing` to be the `Thing` object with id '1a'.

**EDIT**

You also really shouldn't have to put the `<Thing>` portion in since it will be implied by the first argument but I'm leaving it in there for clarity.

Comment: It will be easier to figure out how to fix it if you will provide an example of how you call this function. What data type do you want to pass to this fn ?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqEvm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? In either case it would be very helpful if you could show a call to the function from the outside, with some example data structure.

Comment: @jcalz that may work but I'm still kind of new to TypeScript coming from c# so I'm not sure I really understand what's going on in the type definitions.  Any chance you have a brief explanation of the concept here?

Comment: Added an example call with sample data.

Comment: @jcalz Update... I tried it in the playground and it seems to do what I want.  However, as mentioned I don't know that I fully understand why.  If you don't mind writing up an answer with a bit of detail on what this is doing exactly I would be happy to accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: Your example should be a [mre] suitable for pasting into an IDE; there are typos in there (no commas between properties) and `Thing` is not defined.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining it, but could you fix the example code so that it works in an IDE directly?

Comment: (btw it might be a little while before I can write up the answer... briefly we are making the function generic in the keys for id and children and constraining `T` to something with a `string` property at the id key and with a `T[]` property at the children key, so that the compiler understands that it can expect `x[idKey]` to be a `string` and `i[childrenField]` to be an array of the same type.

Comment: Ok great thank you.  I just updated with what should be minimally reproducible.  I'll watch for the answer and accept it when you post.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler has no idea that the property at the `idField` key of an object of type `T` is `string`-valued, so it won't let you compare it to a string.  Additionally it has no idea that the property at the `childrenField` key of an object of type `T` is array-of-`T`-valued, so it won't let you just call `GetGenericItemById` on it.

In order to convey this to the compiler, you will need to make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both the type of `idField`, call it `IK`, and the type of the `childrenField`, call it `CK`.  Then we want to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to be an object type with a `string` property at key `IK` and a `T[]` property at key `CK`.

One way to write that type is

```
Record<IK, string> &
Record<CK, T[]> &
Record<string, any>
```

This uses [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to represent "an object with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`], and [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to combine the constraints together.  You can think of that as "an object with a `string` property at key `IK`, *and* a `T[]` property at key `CK`, *and* any property at any `string` keys.  The last bit with `Record<string, any>` is not necessary, but it lowers the chance that the `allItems` parameter will be rejected for having [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

Here's the function now with no errors:

```
function GetGenericItemById<
  IK extends string,
  CK extends string,
  T extends Record<string, any> & Record<IK, string> & Record<CK, T[]>
>(
  allItems: T[],
  idField: IK,
  childrenField: CK,
  id: string
): T | undefined {
  const item = allItems.find((x) => x[idField] === id); // okay
  if (item != null) {
    return item;
  }

  const subItems = allItems.flatMap((i) => i[childrenField]);

  if (subItems.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return GetGenericItemById(subItems, idField, childrenField, id); // okay
}
```

Those errors are gone because now the compiler knows that `x[idField]` is a `string` and that `subItems` is a `T[]`.

The return type has been changed from `any` to `T | undefined`, so calls to `GetGenericItemById` will have strongly typed results.  Let's test it:

```
GetGenericItemById(
  topThings,
  'id',
  'children',
  '1a'
)?.name.toUpperCase(); // THING 1A
```

Looks good; the compiler accepts the call, and the return value is of type `Thing | undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&module=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcQKZTWVAnGECSUqAtgEICe+AJgDwBQii+A0oqgB5FhUDOiPUXGADmAGgaIAwqw5de-QTBHjGAFTadU3PgCVUEONlotRCocIB8iAGSI9BozWmnVAbQC6V2-cO0B50wBDMHILOgsACglAgBsYwhIeAC5EN3cVRBgqADEYVBiqFJMJCAALGALsLVz8wqlmDKyU-yVhOgBKFPUAH0RwKlRgJVQqRABvEoQBTKJiRABeRFj42Z4AOiHuCIj2doWrdlcsmoL3BfnFrPaAbgkYYEQImFnEAEJFsBA4vYnGRiqoCBsEhniRbowAL50SZgaY8EAAIwSxD4i2WyPWwBigSgAFlAgAHbYwPbzKwwVxlCpUKpgE5Udw3aGMe6PeFI1ZrGJaYRQUrnRYABh+En+6CBSH6g2GVHBiChEgBEpQ6EwODwyIo1Ai7IxpmOeQKpiplWqhqo+qoTIVdCURGwwECEFQqXKInGEjAgWIqGaihEcqaZlacpNNK0XTdwg8twVBlhUEQUDgBNUUeSrtaHgWiFcEl+fy9PpSACI+a1EABGEsZFl1EvV2uIMO0lJ5v5-AsdxhF32IMtRquBGui7tBhvDpsdlsR3PuUeQ0fzyEZLuIXul8vugBMI47493TZnYDbC493cL3r7A4r28nZ7rpbve4vzfKppPc7PUI7y-ldHcW46DQDAtHVAhZi1KgokYZNU3TDIAHIskQpDj1QiREMrQJEI6AB+NZezWZMAFUCQJHBJECHhUAiG5EAAegY1IAAl8AAOWQKsAEE6CAA)

Comment: Actually looking at this there is one tweak.  As written the id and child fields accept any string still, so you can put in 'turkey' for the id field and it will compile even though there is no `turkey` property on `Thing`.  I updated to `IK extends keyof T` (similar for `CK`) and that seems to fix it.  The error it gives is slightly wonky as it says the `T[]` is not the right type instead of the property name is wrong but that's easy enough to figure out.

Comment: If `turkey` is not a property of `Thing` then you will get an error with my code above (it’s “wonky” but it is there) Can you demonstrate otherwise? Possibly with a playground link (you can use tsplay.dev to shorten)